# Bios boot menu entries

Tags: kubuntu, bios

Kubuntu 20.04.1
In the bios of my laptop in the boot menu section i have several entries with the operating system that i installed previously for example : Windows boot manager , Pop os , Endless os.

Is it possible to delete these entries from the bios and how could i delete them ?

[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Comment: _Had the same Problem with a `Phoenix SecureCore` bios. To remove it I selected the ubuntu entry and pressed `DEL` a small `x` appeared at it's left. After saving and rebooting it was gone._ Answer from @P3trus